# Are unofficial python binaries safe?

Tags: python, pyaudio, pyttsx3

I was working a on python project in vscode in which I have need to install PyAudio but pip method isn't working so I found the method of unofficial python binaries for windows but I have a doubt are those binaries safe for my PC? Is that going to corrupt files or OS? Do they access data or hardware? or They send some data or enter viruses? or Is there any other method to install pyaudio?

Comment: Where did you find those binaries? There are some well respected distributors like https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Maybe you should post how you tried to install the libraries with `pip` and show where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes Binaries Were From ~gohlke/pythonlibs, are those binaries safe for computer? I tried to install pyaudio with both pip and pipwin but none of them worked for pipwin it was showing this - pipwin : The term 'pipwin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 4):

No - a program from *anywhere* can be unsafe

Your only assurances are

- ability to inspect the source code and compile the program yourself
- threat of lawsuit (value of compromising your system compared with the value of the source company)
- restricted environments (JavaScript, airgapped system)

If you can't guarantee at least one is true, you're very likely at risk

Comment: I found those binaries on ~gohlke/pythonlibs which is a very popular website for binaries, but just here to ask are ~gohlke/pythonlibs binaries are 100% safe?

Comment: reading the other comments and more, these look good and highly legitimate - however, practically, what would the consequences of the binaries they host there being unsafe and why wouldn't they be? perhaps they or their group would lose their job at the university? are they sufficiently skilled to know that they are providing unsafe binaries in case their systems were compromised to produce unsafe ones? (likely also yes) do they have any motive to provide unsafe binaries? (likely no) the PSF has made them a fellow https://www.python.org/psf/fellows/ indicating deep trust from the official org

Answer (score 1):

Preferably do not use any software from unreliable sources. It may harm your system.